# How to build url to yelp review using yelp API?

Tags: api, review, yelp

How to build url to yelp review using yelp API?

```
"reviews": [
    {
      "excerpt": "This is by far my favorite breakfast food. They have the best plain grits and one of the best omelets I\u0027ve ever had. The grits require no extra seasoning,...",
      "id": "N95_f0ssLhVk-3_adcm0HA",
      "rating": 5.0,
      "rating_image_large_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/22affc4e6c38/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_5.png",
      "rating_image_small_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/c7623205d5cd/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_5.png",
      "rating_image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/f1def11e4e79/ico/stars/v1/stars_5.png",
      "time_created": 1.456714839E9,
      "user": {
        "id": "v6q8B9nEHBK25EuNIUF09g",
        "image_url": "http://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/photo/zzXwod9kRw5BC-OZn2S6Dg/ms.jpg",
        "name": "Ashley M."
      }
    }
```

I can see the review information here, but I can't see link to the review to do smth like "read more". Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be smth like that:

```
url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?")) + "?hrid=" + reviewId;
```